# Can django lazy-load fields in a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

One of my django models has a large `TextField` which I often don't need to use.  Is there a way to tell django to "lazy-load" this field? i.e. not to bother pulling it from the database unless I explicitly ask for it.  I'm wasting a lot of memory and bandwidth pulling this `TextField` into python every time I refer to these objects.

The alternative would be to create a new table for the contents of this field, but I'd rather avoid that complexity if I can.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The functionality happens when you make the query, using the `defer()` statement, instead of in the model definition. Check it out here in the docs:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer

Now, actually, your alternative solution of refactoring and pulling the data into another table is a really good solution. Some people would say that the need to lazy load fields means there is a design flaw, and the data should have been modeled differently.

Either way works, though!

Answer (score 9):

There are two options for lazy-loading in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only

- defer(*fields)

  Avoid loading those fields that require expensive processing to convert them to Python objects.

  `Entry.objects.defer("text")`
- only(*fields)

  Only load the fields that you actually need

  `Person.objects.only("name")`

  Personally, I think `only` is better than `defer` since the code is not only easier to understand, but also more maintainable in the long run.

Answer (score 7):

For something like this you can just override the default manager.  Usually, it's not advised but for a defer() it makes sense:

```
    class CustomManager(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super(CustomManager, self).get_queryset().defer('YOUR_TEXTFIELD_FIELDNAME')

    class DjangoModel(models.Model):
        objects = CustomerManager()
```