# Ignore one field in a django model

Tags: python, django

I have a django model that has the following four fields:

```
class File:
    id = models.PrimaryKey()
    name = models.CharField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    data = models.JSONField()
```

The `data` field is massive, perhaps 5MB per entry. Is there a way I can hide that field when I do an ORM query without having to specify all the fields I want to view each time? Something like:

```
File.objects.all() # exclude data field
File.objects.values('id', 'data') # include the data field
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057916/can-django-lazy-load-fields-in-a-model) on how to lazy-load fields in a model, which I think is what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some complex data-modeling situations, your models might contain a lot of fields, some of which could contain a lot of data (for example, text fields), or require expensive processing to convert them to Python objects. If you are using the results of a queryset in some situation where you don’t know if you need those particular fields when you initially fetch the data, you can tell Django not to retrieve them from the database.

This is done by passing the names of the fields to not load to `defer()`:

```
Entry.objects.defer("headline", "body")
```

Also mention that, Whenever you call `only()` it replaces the set of fields to load immediately. The method’s name is mnemonic: only those fields are loaded immediately; the remainder are deferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only() to specify the fields you want

```
File.objects.only('id', 'data')
```